# TSQL round number and check in which group it is

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a quite simple task:
I must check in wchich group my float is.

Here are my groups:

- 0-30 display "(0-30)"
- 30-40 display "(0-30)"
- 40-50 display "(0-30)"
- 50-60 display "(0-30)"
- etc

I have created a simple script:

```
DECLARE @num FLOAT
SET @num = 42.5;
SELECT CASE WHEN @num<=30 THEN '(0-30)' 
           ELSE  '('+convert(VARCHAR,convert(INT,round((@num/10),0))*10)+'-'+convert(VARCHAR,convert(INT,round(((@num+10)/10),0))*10)+')' 
       END
```

I think it is a little lame, so if anyone could help me out with creating a better solution :)

Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: According to your question you are always displaying "(0-30)". I presume this is an error.

Comment: Can you be clear on your upper and lower bounds. Which ones are inclusive or exclusive? (E.g. if the value is exactly 30, does it go into `(0-30)` or `(30-40)`?)

Comment: If value is exactly 30 i must display (0-30) - @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: I only display (0-30) if @num is smaller or equals 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
DECLARE @num FLOAT
SET @num = 311.2;
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN @num <= 30
        THEN '(0-30)'
    ELSE '(' + cast(cast(@num AS INT) / 10 * 10 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + cast(cast(@num AS INT) / 10 * 10 + 10 AS VARCHAR) + ')' END
```

Comment: Why `varchar(max)`? This has an overhead compared with using `varchar(1-8000)` and doesn't seem to be required.

Comment: This is basically my solution except using cast instead convert. Is cast faster? Safer?

Comment: @Misiu, It is shorter... Also it doesn't use `round`.

Comment: @MartinSmith, It is only a sample. I didn't consider any performance issues.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll use this one :) One more thing: do I must use varchar(max) or can I use varchar in last cast?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use: (to get rid of the CASE statement and get a more readable look, IMO)

```
declare @num float = 156

select
    '(' + convert(varchar, lowLimit) + ' - ' + convert(varchar, highLimit) + ')'
from
    (
        select
            0 as lowLimit,
            30 as highLimit
        where
            @num <= 30

        union all

        select
            floor(@num/10)*10,
            ceiling(@num/10)*10
        where
            @num > 30
    ) limits
```

Comment: I don't want to use select, I'm building a 100+ rows report which uses 5 tables, multiple selects, so another one won't be very usefull.